# How do I move a cache to spark storage from the driver?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

If I have:

```
SparkSession spk = SparkSession.builder().master("somewhere").getOrCreate();
Dataset<Row> x = spk.createDataFrame(someList);
```

How do I instruct spark to take x and distribute it immediately among worker nodes such that memory on the driver is freed, such that more can be loaded? I'd like to use a small host to load up data, which is processed on the workers. Is `x.repartition(numWorkers).cache()` sufficient?

Comment: The only way I see would be to make `someList` be garbage collected. Which would mean get `x` to be garbage collected too. Which would mean clearing its reference, and not using it, which is not the point. Therefore, my advise would be to ship `somelist` or `x` to your datastore (HDFS ? SQL database ? Hive ?) in some form, and recreate `x` based on a dataframe backed by this store.

Comment: If I ship it into a RDD first, will it prevent the GC from eating it? `RDD<T> rdd = jsc.parallelize(q).rdd().persist(MEMORY_ONLY);`